# Get taxonomy term field from where is attached

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy vocabulary like this:

```
A
|--B(branch_field)
   |-- C(branch_field)

X
|--Y(branch_field)
   |-- Z(branch_field)
```

Each user has a reference to a taxonomy term.
I need to create a view where I pass taxonomy term attached to user for filtering data, but I need also to use the taxonomy term field "branch" in the view but I don't manage it.

This is what I see using Devel about user fields:

```
[field_category_user] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [target_id] => 39
                            )

                    )

            )
```

Can I expose term field and target id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement hook_views_query_alter()

1. In your view create a filter (not exposed) to field_category_user, with default value -1. If field_category_user is not aviable you need create a realation to taxonomy.
2. Create a hook_views_query_alter() in file [module_name].views_execution.inc with some like this:

   // Implements hook_views_query_alter().

   ```
   function [module_name]_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
   $id = $view->id();

   switch ($id) {
       case '[your_view_id]':
           $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
           $field_category_user = !$user->field_category_user->isEmpty() ? $user->field_category_user->value : null;

           if(!$field_category_user){
               return;
           }

           //Set field_category_user id to where condition
           foreach ($query->where as $key => $item) {
               foreach($item['conditions'] as $items){
                   if ($items['field'] == 'field_category_user') { //Verify if field_category_user is the id of filter
                       $query->where[$key]['conditions'][0]['value'] = $field_category_user->id();
                   }
               }
           }
       break;
   }}
   ```